# Insert data in data format from "google.type.date" protocol buffers

Tags: python, protocol-buffers

I have this messsage in probuf:

```
message Date {
    uint32 year = 1;
    MONTH month = 2;
    uint32 day = 3; 
}
```

```
message Professor{
    uint32 id = 1;
    string name = 2;
    Date birth_date = 3;
    string phone = 4;
    string address = 5;
}
```

I have this code in python to insert data:

```
def School() -> proto_exp_pb2.School:
    message = proto_exp_pb2.School()
    message.prof.id = 42
    message.prof.name = "My name"
    message.prof.birth_date = today
    message.prof.phone = "+000544454544"
    message.prof.address = "Seventh street"
    message.students.add(id=43, name="My name 2", gender = 1)
    message.students.add(id=44, name="My name 3")
    return message
```

But i get this error:

message.prof.birth_date = today
AttributeError: Assignment not allowed to message, map, or repeated field "birth_date" in protocol message object.

What is the correct way to insert a date format that fits in the message?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not easily reproducible. Your proto and code don't match; there's no `School`, `MONTH` (nor `Student`) message.

The field `birth_date` is a type `Date` that you define to have fields of `uint32` and the undefined message type `MONTH`.

Python is a little awkward for sub-messages but, once you've created the root type (i.e. `proto_exp_pb2.School()`), sub-messages don't need to be created (i.e. no `proto_exp_pb2.Date()`), you just assign the fields, i.e.:

I revised your proto so that it compiles:

```protobuf
syntax = "proto3";

message Date {
    uint32 year = 1;
    uint32 month = 2;
    uint32 day = 3; 
}
message Professor {
    uint32 id = 1;
    string name = 2;
    Date birth_date = 3;
    string phone = 4;
    string address = 5;
}
message School {
    Professor prof = 1;
}
```

```py
import proto_exp_pb2

message = proto_exp_pb2.School()
message.prof.id = 42
message.prof.name = "My name"
message.prof.birth_date.year = 2022
message.prof.birth_date.month = 11
message.prof.birth_date.day = 1
message.prof.phone = "+000544454544"
message.prof.address = "Seventh street"

# No such type
# message.students.add(id=43, name="My name 2", gender = 1)
# message.students.add(id=44, name="My name 3")

print(message)
```

It adds some initial complexity but Google provides so-called [Well-Known Types](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/google.protobuf) for commonly-needed types including [`Timestamp`](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/google.protobuf#google.protobuf.Timestamp). This saves repeatedly defining common types and can make reusing values easier.

You must import these types to use them, i.e:

```protobuf
syntax = "proto3";

import "google/protobuf/timestamp.proto";

message Professor {
    uint32 id = 1;
    string name = 2;
    google.protobuf.Timestamp birth_date = 3;
    string phone = 4;
    string address = 5;
}
message School {
    Professor prof = 1;
}
```

And then you can convert to/from Python [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html)

```py
import datetime

import proto_exp_pb2


dt = datetime.datetime(2022, 11, 1)

message = proto_exp_pb2.School()
message.prof.id = 42
message.prof.name = "My name"
message.prof.birth_date.FromDatetime(dt)
message.prof.phone = "+000544454544"
message.prof.address = "Seventh street"
# message.students.add(id=43, name="My name 2", gender = 1)
# message.students.add(id=44, name="My name 3")

print(message)
```